# How to change background color of CountryListPick? flutter package

Tags: flutter, dark-theme

The default background is white. In my app I am applying dark theme so I need to change the background color to black and the name of countries in white.[image]

```
CountryListPick(
theme: CountryTheme(
isShowFlag: true,
isShowTitle: false,
isShowCode: false,
isDownIcon: true,
showEnglishName: true,
),
initialSelection: Globals.initialPhoneCode,
onChanged: (code) =>
phoneNumberController.text = code!.dialCode!,
useUiOverlay: true,
useSafeArea: false
),
```

Comment: can you add the code or explain more detail ?